# NIntegrate returned zero

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to calculate the following integral and expecting the result to be one but instead returning to 0.  This is the formal solution for tunneling Gaussian wavepackets for a finite-range potential.

```
    φ0[σ_, x0_, κ0_, d_, ω0_, 
   t_, τ_, ν0_, x_] = 
  1/(2 π)^(1/4) 1/Sqrt[σ]
    Exp[I (κ0 (x - d) - ω0 t)]/Sqrt[(1 + (I t)/τ)]
    Exp[-((x - d - x0 - ν0 t)^2/(
     4 σ^2 (1 + (I t)/τ)))];

z[m_, ℏ_, x_, d_, t_, τ_, κ0_, ν0_, α_, 
   x0_] = Exp[-((I π)/4)] Sqrt[m/(
   2 ℏ (t - I τ))] (x - d - 
     x0 - ν0 t + (ℏ (κ0 + (I α^2)/(2 d)) (t - 
        I τ))/m);

m1[m_, ℏ_, x_, d_, t_, τ_, κ0_, ν0_, α_, 
   x0_] = Exp[(I m (x - d - x0 - ν0 t)^2)/(
    2 ℏ (t - I τ))] Exp[
    z[m, ℏ, x, d, t, τ, κ0, ν0, α, x0]^2];

φ[m_?NumericQ, ℏ_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ, 
   x0_?NumericQ, κ0_?NumericQ, 
   d_?NumericQ, ω0_?NumericQ, 
   t_?NumericQ, τ_?NumericQ, α_?NumericQ, ν0_?
    NumericQ, λ_?NumericQ, 
   x_?NumericQ] = φ0[σ, x0, κ0, d, ω0, 
    t, τ, ν0, x] - 
   1/(2 π)^(1/4) 1/Sqrt[σ] E^(
    I (κ0 (x - d) - ω0 t))
     Sqrt[π] ((2 m σ λ d)/ℏ^2) m1[m, ℏ,
      x, d, t, τ, κ0, ν0, α, x0];

NIntegrate[φ[0.067*9.11*10^-31, 1.05*10^-34, 
   5*10^-10, -50*10^-10, 1.098*10^18, 2.5*10^-10, 1.52*10^12, 10^-12, 
   2.9*10^-16, 0.1047, 1.9*10^15, 3.204*10^-29, 
   x]^2, {x, -∞, ∞}]

φ[m_?NumericQ, ℏ_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ, 
   x0_?NumericQ, κ0_?NumericQ, 
   d_?NumericQ, ω0_?NumericQ, 
   t_?NumericQ, τ_?NumericQ, α_?NumericQ, ν0_?
    NumericQ, λ_?NumericQ, 
   x_?NumericQ] = φ0[σ, x0, κ0, d, ω0, 
    t, τ, ν0, x] - 
   1/(2 π)^(1/4) 1/Sqrt[σ] E^(
    I (κ0 (x - d) - ω0 t))
     Sqrt[π] ((2 m σ λ d)/ℏ^2) m1[m, ℏ,
      x, d, t, τ, κ0, ν0, α, x0];

NIntegrate[φ[0.067*9.11*10^-31, 1.05*10^-34, 
   5*10^-10, -50*10^-10, 1.098*10^18, 2.5*10^-10, 1.52*10^12, 10^-12, 
   2.9*10^-16, 0.1047, 1.9*10^15, 3.204*10^-29, 
   x]^2, {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

The error message is:

> NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option.
>   [image]

Comment: Did you try plotting your functions to see how it behaves, and to get an idea about what sorts of numerical errors to expect?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I didn't but will try.

Comment: @Szabolcs, this is the plot I got

Comment: You seem to be integrating extremely sharply peaked Gaussians. You might want to consider rewriting the problem in a from that is more amenable to numerical calculation.

Comment: @mmeent, I want to normalize Eq. 27 in the paper https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.75.012111

Comment: @Szabolcs, the equation is the solution of the time-dependent Schrodinger equation for cutoff Gaussian wave packet which is identical to Eq. (27) in the above paper. I couldn't get arxiv link.

Comment: I get `Underflow[]` everywhere.  You should try rescaling the problem so that the bulk of the function is greater than, say, `10^-308`.  Or if you know where the function has large values, add them to the interval: E.g., if `f[200]` does not underflow, then `{x, -Infinity, 200, Infinity}`.